# Typescript Array - Splice & Insert

Tags: arrays, angular, typescript

I have 3 arrays here of type channel array.

```
currentPickSelection: Array<channel>;
draggedChannel: channel;
droppedChannel: channel;
```

What I am trying to do is remove an item(the droppedChannel array item)from the currentPickSelection array and insert the draggedChannel item array onto the same index of the removed item.
Here is what I did so far, everything works except the insert part:

```
 let index = this.currentPickSelection.findIndex(item => item === this.droppedChannel);
 this.currentPickSelection.splice(index, 1, this.draggedChannel);
```

An this is the way I have the channel model declared:

```
export class CompChannel {
    constructor(public compChannelCbsCode: string, 
        public compChannelName: string, 
        public compChannelLogo: string) {}
}

export class channel {
    public pickCode: string;
    public cbsCode: string;
    public channel: string;
    public logo: string;
    public compChannel: CompChannel[];

    constructor(pickCode: string, cbsCode: string, channel: string,
        logo: string, compChannel: CompChannel[]) {
        this.pickCode = pickCode;
        this.cbsCode = cbsCode;
        this.channel = channel;
        this.logo = logo;
        this.compChannel = compChannel;
    }
}
```

Please advise what is wrong!

Comment: You're comparing a channel with an array of channels. Given the name of the variables, draggedChannel and droppedChannel should be **a** channel, not an array of channels.

Comment: draggedChannel & droppedChannel, they are just single channels, but the currentPickSelection array is an array of channels

Comment: OK. Then why did you declare draggedChannel and droppedChannel as `Array<channel>`?

Comment: This is the output of the dragged Channel channel {pickCode: "785", cbsCode: "COMEDY", channel: "Comedy Network", logo: "/assets/Comedy Network.jpg", compChannel: Array(1)} and this is the output of the droppedChannel  channel {pickCode: "800", cbsCode: "SHCASE", channel: "Showcase", logo: "/assets/Showcase.png", compChannel: Array(1)}

Comment: Does it work if you declare: `draggedChannel: channel; droppedChannel: channel;`, as suggested by @JBNizet?

Comment: hi @ConnorsFan, I edited my original post with the new code snippets, Still i get errors. It says " Cannot read property 'compChannel' of undefined"

Answer (score 0):

The `droppedChannel` object and the item found in `currentPickSelection` may not the exact **same copy/clone** of each other.

Try to compare with an unique value(like `pickCode` or `cbsCode`) in `findIndex` method instead of comparing with the whole object.

```
let currentPickSelection: any[] = [
 { id: 1, label: 'Test1' },
 { id: 2, label: 'Test2' },
 { id: 3, label: 'Test3' }
];
let draggedChannel: any = { id: 5, label: 'Test5' };
let droppedChannel: any = { id: 3, label: 'Test3' };
let index = currentPickSelection.findIndex(item => {
   return item.id == droppedChannel.id; //use unique value instead of item object
});
if (index > -1) 
 currentPickSelection.splice(index, 1, draggedChannel);
```